# Conceptual question regarding conection in metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I have to give an example of two sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that both are connected, but $A\cup B$ is not. So I thought of a trivial example $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $(2,3) \subset \mathbb{R}$ which are both connected since they are intervals an the union is clearly a not connected set. However, when I try to define a disconection $A\cup B$ with $A,B$ clopen, I get really confused because I dont't know if $A,B$ have to be clopen in relation to $\mathbb{R}$ or to $A\cup B$.

Comment: In relation to $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they were clopen with respect to $\Bbb{R}$, then $\Bbb{R}$ wouldn't be connected...

It is important to note that a topological space is connected (or not) independently of any embedding in a larger space. For example, topologically the space $(0,1) \cup (2,3) \subset \Bbb{R}$ behaves exactly like $\big(\{0\} \times (0,1)\big) \cup \big(\{0\} \times (2,3)\big) \subset \Bbb{R}^2$, even though the topologies on $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ are quite different.